# Why can't add link tag for expanded html:5?

Tags: html, vim, emmet

html:5 will be expanded as following by default with emmet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to customize it as following when to expand html:5 in my vim.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link  href="" >
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my try .

```
vim snippets.json
#to change the line containing doc": as
doc": "html>(head>meta[charset=${charset}]+meta:vp+meta:edge+link[href=\"\"])+body",
```

Why still no link tag when to expand html:5?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you are using the [emmet-vim](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) plugin.

It stores the complete `emmet` configuration, including the snippets section, inside
the `.vim/autoload/emmet.vim` file, which is why it does not see the changes you make to your standalone `snippets.json` file.

Here is what [plugin documentation](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981) at vim.org says:

> You can customize behavior of expanding with overriding config.
>   This configuration will be merged at loading plugin.

```
let g:user_emmet_settings = {
\  'indentation' : '  ',
\  'perl' : {
\    'aliases' : {
\      'req' : 'require '
\    },
\    'snippets' : {
\      'use' : "use strict\nuse warnings\n\n",
\      'warn' : "warn \"|\";",
\    }
\  }
\}
```

So, what you have to do, to add `<link/>` to the `html:5` snippet, is add the following to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
let g:user_emmet_settings = {
\  'html' : {
\      'snippets' : {
\            'html:5': "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
\                    ."<html lang=\"${lang}\">\n"
\                    ."<head>\n"
\                    ."\t<meta charset=\"${charset}\">\n"
\                    ."\t<title></title>\n"
\                    ."\t<link href=\"\">"
\                    ."</head>\n"
\                    ."<body>\n\t${child}|\n</body>\n"
\                    ."</html>"
\      }
\   }
\}
```

now when you restart vim and type `html:5 <c-y>,` it will produce what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="">
</head>
<body>
```

Alternatively, install the [Vim WebAPI plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4019), and load your custom `snippets.json` with it, like this:

`~/.vimrc`

```
let g:user_emmet_settings = webapi#json#decode(join(readfile(expand('~/snippets.json')), "\n"))
```

`~/snippets.json`

```
{
"html" : {
    "snippets": {
        "html:5": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n <html lang=\"${lang}\">\n<head>\n \t<meta charset=\"${charset}\">\n \t<title></title>\n \t<link href=\"\"> </head>\n <body>\n\t${child}|\n</body>\n </html>"
        }
    }
}
```